# Fundamental problems with the understanding of probability currents

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

For the Normalization of the Schrödinger wave equation we need the following to be true
$$\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x=1
\end{equation}$$
Now, if I write in variable separable form the wave function $|\psi(x,t)|=|f(x)||g(t)|$, then we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2|g(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x=|g(t)|^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x=1$$, since for any square integratable function $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ will be a finite constant, hence $|g(t)|$ will also be a constant.

Now, let us look at the probability current of the particle in a localized neighbourhood $(a<x<b)$.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(a<x<b)=\left(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|g(t)|^2$$

Now, since I've established above, that $|g(t)|$ is a constant, hence the probability current through a predetermined neighbourhood should always be zero. Where am I going wrong, kindly help, I'm not a physicist but I'm having to do some material science right now.

Comment: Looks correct, apart from the last integration boundaries. What you showed is that separable states are 'stationary'. General states are superpositions if separable states.

Comment: But, if all separable states are stationary, the general state would be a sum of the stationary states which would logically itself be another stationary state. Then Probability currents lose their significance in that all probability currents of quantum states would be zero.

Comment: No. Add two like f1g1 and f2g2 *then* absolutsquare them and you see that the aforementioned reasoning does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no probability current for steady states: their probability density is time-independent.  However for linear combinations of time-dependent solutions (which are not separable in $t$ and $x$) the probability current can be $\ne 0$.

Take $\Psi(x,t)= a \psi_0(x)e^{-i\omega t/2} + b\psi_1(x)e^{-i3\omega t/2}  $ as linear combinations of harmonic oscillator states with any $a,b$ such that $aa^*+bb^*=1$ as an example...